# PDFBox renderImageWithDPI produces images with missing content due to absent embedded fonts - how do I resolve this?

Tags: pdfbox

PDFBox renderImageWithDPI only partially renders text because of missing embedded(?) fonts.

- Using **PDFBox 2.0.28** then tried **PDFBox 3.0.0-RC1**
- Created a PDDocument using Loader.loadPDF
- Created a PDFRenderer from the PDDocument
- Executed renderImageWithDPI(pagenum, dpi, RGBObj) on PDDocument
- Obtained java.awt.image.BufferedImage
- Write as jpg using javax.imageio.ImageIO
- However, there is missing content in the images
- Extracted 2 sample problematic pages from the pdf using [PDFSam basic](https://pdfsam.org/)
- [Pg 1](https://easyupload.io/ozvofw) which generates [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jaxip.jpg)
- and [Pg 2](https://easyupload.io/c38q8w) which generated [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrFhA.jpg)
- Have highlighted areas where the content is missing.
- On executing PreflightParser.validate obtain the messages below:-

```
1.4 : Trailer Syntax error, /XRef cross reference streams are not allowed
5.2.2 : Forbidden field in an annotation definition, Flags of Link annotation are invalid
2.3.2 : Unexpected value for key in Graphic object definition, Unexpected 'true' value for 'Interpolate' Key
2.4.2 : Invalid Color space, The operator "k" can't be used with RGB Profile
2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, The operator "f" can't be used without Color Profile
3.1.4 : Invalid Font definition, ELWKFI+OptimaLTStd: The Charset entry is missing for the Type1 Subset
3.1.4 : Invalid Font definition, JECWGC+InsigniaLTStd: The Charset entry is missing for the Type1 Subset
3.1.4 : Invalid Font definition, PHSMMZ+OptimaLTStd-Bold: The Charset entry is missing for the Type1 Subset
3.1.4 : Invalid Font definition, EHCNNL+OptimaLTStd-Italic: The Charset entry is missing for the Type1 Subset
3.1.4 : Invalid Font definition, QBVSKF+HelveticaLTStd-Obl: The Charset entry is missing for the Type1 Subset
3.1.9 : Invalid Font definition, UBAPGG+OptimaLTStd: mandatory CIDToGIDMap missing
3.1.11 : Invalid Font definition, UBAPGG+OptimaLTStd: The CIDSet entry is missing for the Composite Subset
3.2.3 : Font damaged, UBAPGG+OptimaLTStd: The FontFile can't be read
3.1.9 : Invalid Font definition, ORMCFE+HelveticaLTStd-Obl: mandatory CIDToGIDMap missing
3.1.11 : Invalid Font definition, ORMCFE+HelveticaLTStd-Obl: The CIDSet entry is missing for the Composite Subset
3.2.3 : Font damaged, ORMCFE+HelveticaLTStd-Obl: The FontFile can't be read
3.1.9 : Invalid Font definition, TFEWKU+HelveticaLTStd-Roman: mandatory CIDToGIDMap missing
3.1.11 : Invalid Font definition, TFEWKU+HelveticaLTStd-Roman: The CIDSet entry is missing for the Composite Subset
3.2.3 : Font damaged, TFEWKU+HelveticaLTStd-Roman: The FontFile can't be read
3.1.4 : Invalid Font definition, CRQQXS+OptimaLTStd: The Charset entry is missing for the Type1 Subset
3.1.4 : Invalid Font definition, MVVAWX+InsigniaLTStd: The Charset entry is missing for the Type1 Subset
3.1.4 : Invalid Font definition, YIWFBD+OptimaLTStd-Bold: The Charset entry is missing for the Type1 Subset
3.1.11 : Invalid Font definition, JYHLHF+OptimaLTStd: The CIDSet entry is missing for the Composite Subset
3.1.9 : Invalid Font definition, LDXBBC+OptimaLTStd: mandatory CIDToGIDMap missing
3.1.11 : Invalid Font definition, LDXBBC+OptimaLTStd: The CIDSet entry is missing for the Composite Subset
3.2.3 : Font damaged, LDXBBC+OptimaLTStd: The FontFile can't be read
3.1.9 : Invalid Font definition, FSNSYC+OptimaLTStd: mandatory CIDToGIDMap missing
3.1.11 : Invalid Font definition, FSNSYC+OptimaLTStd: The CIDSet entry is missing for the Composite Subset
3.2.3 : Font damaged, FSNSYC+OptimaLTStd: The FontFile can't be read
3.1.9 : Invalid Font definition, LVYKUL+InsigniaLTStd: mandatory CIDToGIDMap missing
3.1.11 : Invalid Font definition, LVYKUL+InsigniaLTStd: The CIDSet entry is missing for the Composite Subset
3.2.3 : Font damaged, LVYKUL+InsigniaLTStd: The FontFile can't be read
3.1.9 : Invalid Font definition, FUYTUP+OptimaLTStd-Italic: mandatory CIDToGIDMap missing
3.1.11 : Invalid Font definition, FUYTUP+OptimaLTStd-Italic: The CIDSet entry is missing for the Composite Subset
3.2.3 : Font damaged, FUYTUP+OptimaLTStd-Italic: The FontFile can't be read
3.1.9 : Invalid Font definition, GZVYQO+OptimaLTStd-Bold: mandatory CIDToGIDMap missing
3.1.11 : Invalid Font definition, GZVYQO+OptimaLTStd-Bold: The CIDSet entry is missing for the Composite Subset
3.2.3 : Font damaged, GZVYQO+OptimaLTStd-Bold: The FontFile can't be read
3.1.9 : Invalid Font definition, GWNIWZ+HelveticaLTStd-Roman: mandatory CIDToGIDMap missing
3.1.11 : Invalid Font definition, GWNIWZ+HelveticaLTStd-Roman: The CIDSet entry is missing for the Composite Subset
3.2.3 : Font damaged, GWNIWZ+HelveticaLTStd-Roman: The FontFile can't be read
7.1 : Error on MetaData, Metadata is not a stream
```

Which also corroborate to execution warnings

```
May 26, 2023 12:40:01 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
WARNING: Could not read embedded OTF for font GWNIWZ+HelveticaLTStd-Roman
java.io.IOException: head is mandatory
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:182)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:150)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:79)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:27)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:73)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.<init>(PDCIDFontType2.java:114)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.<init>(PDCIDFontType2.java:67)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createDescendantFont(PDFontFactory.java:138)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.<init>(PDType0Font.java:88)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:96)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:143)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize.process(SetFontAndSize.java:66)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:849)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:495)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:469)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:142)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:264)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:338)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:259)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(PDFRenderer.java:245)
```

Additional truncated messages

```
May 26, 2023 12:40:00 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
WARNING: Could not read embedded OTF for font UBAPGG+OptimaLTStd
java.io.IOException: head is mandatory

May 26, 2023 12:40:01 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
WARNING: Could not read embedded OTF for font GZVYQO+OptimaLTStd-Bold
java.io.IOException: head is mandatory

May 26, 2023 12:40:01 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
WARNING: Could not read embedded OTF for font FUYTUP+OptimaLTStd-Italic
java.io.IOException: head is mandatory

May 26, 2023 12:40:01 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
WARNING: Could not read embedded OTF for font FSNSYC+OptimaLTStd
java.io.IOException: head is mandatory
```

Although fallback fonts seen to be used they don't work either.

```
May 26, 2023 12:40:01 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 findFontOrSubstitute WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for CID-keyed TrueType font GWNIWZ+HelveticaLTStd-Roman
```

I also see warning messages as below, unsure how to process / address.

```
May 26, 2023 12:40:01 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDICCBased ensureDisplayProfile WARNING: ICC profile is Perceptual, ignoring, treating as Display class
```

Need multiple assistance.

Question 1: How do I add a font?

- If I try using the below, The codeblock below where I get a page and add a font before rendering doesnt have any impact.
- Note, *getDocument()* and *setDocument* and *setPdfRenderer* are convenience methods in my implementation class. *setPdfRenderer()* contains *PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);* and sets it to a class variable.

```
int position = 0;
PDPage page = getDocument().getPage(position);
PDResources resources = page.getResources();
OTFParser otfParser = new OTFParser();
OpenTypeFont otf = otfParser.parse(new File("OptimaLTStd.otf"));
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, otf, false);

resources.add(font);
page.setResources(resources);
if (position == 0) {
   getDocument().getPages().remove(page);
   getDocument().getPages().add(page);
   setDocument(getDocument());
   setPdfRenderer(getDocument());
} else {
   PDPage prevPage = getDocument().getPage(position - 1);
   getDocument().getPages().insertBefore(page, prevPage);
   setDocument(getDocument());
   setPdfRenderer(getDocument());           }
```

- Downloaded OTF from [link](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/a1bc18b26205f46862beafc4d4cbcee0)

Question 2: Do we have an override in pdfrender to skip glyph processing so that font related issues do not impact image generation ?

Comment: Your PDFs contain bad fonts ("head is mandatory"), that's the problem. Preflight is to check for PDF/A, that's something different. PDFBox tries to recover from all this mess, but fails.

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr, Yes the preflight check is how I identified the issues. Wanted guidance if there are any options available to generate the whole page image without trying to process the text. Alternatively need help on how to substitute these bad fonts with proper versions as the approach I tried doesn't work.

Comment: PDFBox does generate the page without processing the text (I tried 2.0.28 and the latest alpha). The error messages don't abort the rendering. The real solution would be to contact the creator of the page. You can also download (buy) the missing fonts. In theory PDFBox should substitute them with other fonts but for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5611

Comment: Please try a snapshot: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.29-SNAPSHOT/  The real cause wasn't the broken font, it was that the width arrays in the PDF for these fonts were all 0.

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr, that did the trick on this pdf. Appreciate you working on updating a new build over the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of the missing text is caused by 0 width definitions for the fonts in the PDF, which incorrectly influences a "stretching" algorithm hen rendering. This has been fixed in ticket [PDFBOX-5611](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5611) and will be in the version 2.0.29. Until then, a [snapshot build](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.29-SNAPSHOT/) will be available.